# Correct formatting of HTML in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using TinyMCE to save some HTML into an SQL table in phpMyAdmin. Inserting and retrieving the row from the table works fine.

I'm using a regex to translate some short codes in the retrieved text and this is where the problem arises.

This is my regular expression, which simply gets the text between two short codes with possible html tags and new lines:

`/(<.+>)?[[]{$code}[]](<\/.+>)?((?:\n.+\n?)+)(<.+>)?[[]{$code}[]](<\/.+>)?/`

When I retrieve the HTML from the DB and run the regex on it, the `preg_match_all()` fails to match anything, but when I double-click on the row in the database and open the in-line editor, phpMyAdmin does...something and performs an update on the row automatically and sets the text to a new value; Then, when I run the regex on the newly updated value, `preg_match_all()` matches the correct values.

I was thinking it was some automatic text encoding conversion or something, but running `mb_detect_encoding()` on the HTML before I insert it  indeed confirms that the encoding is UTF-8 same as the table's `utf8_unicode_ci`.

I then compared the text plus EOL characters before and after the update in Notepad++ and they're exactly the same, yet my regex doesn't work before phpMyAdmin updates it.

What is phpMyAdmin doing to fix the text and how can I do it before it gets inserted in to the database? Why is it automatically updating the row at all?

Comment: If I were you I would save in $_SESSION the value before save it into the DB, then I will get the new value after the update happens on PHPMyAdmin and compare them. Maybe using strlen(), using htmlspecialchars()... Even replacing each character with ord()... I'm just thinking on loud. P.S. if you could show some code or provide a jsfiddle would be better for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some more code to the regular expression to check for content after the short code on the same line and now `preg_match_all()` matches correctly every time. I'm still not sure what's going on there as the content before and after the update are identical in every test I've tried (Same text, same amount of spaces and new line characters).

Regardless, I fixed it by adding the below regex after the check for the end HTML tag:

`(?:.+)?`

So the full expression is:

`(<.+>)?[[]{$code}[]](<\/.+>)?(?:.+)?((?:\n.+\n?)+)(<.+>)?[[]{$code}[]](<\/.+>)?`